# Make an array from associative array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have some code:

```php
$filter = \DB::table('attribute_products')
    ->select('attr_id')
    ->where('product_id', $id)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

This gets me an array like:

[image]

However, I want it like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You want to use the pluck method (https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#retrieving-results)

```
$filter = \DB::table('attribute_products')
        ->where('product_id', $id)
        ->pluck('attr_id');
```

Comment: I just added :  ->pluck('attr_id')->all();

Comment: You shouldn't need `->all()` with `->pluck()`

Answer (score 0):

No need to type `->toarray();`, Just use:

```
$filter = \DB::table('attribute_products')
    ->select('attr_id')
    ->where('product_id', $id)
    ->get()
    ;
```